# AWS Elasticache price list REST api for us-west-1 region of On-Demand nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, web-scraping, amazon-elasticache

I want the cost information node type and price per hour in the form of JSON or CSV. Do AWS already provide this information as REST endpoint?.

Or do I have to scrape the below web page to get the required information?.

https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/pricing/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure there's an API for that (it's AWS, there's almost always an API). Here's how you can get the pricing by regions.

```
import requests
url = "https://b0.p.awsstatic.com/pricing/2.0/meteredUnitMaps/elasticache/USD/current/elasticache.json?timestamp=1598870451424"
r = requests.get(url).json()

for region in r["regions"].values():
    for k, v in region.items():
        print(k)
        print(f"{v['Instance Type']} - {v['price']}")
```

This yields:

```
OnDemand Cache Instance Standard cache m3.2xlarge Memcached Previous Generation
cache.m3.2xlarge - 0.8550000000
OnDemand Cache Instance Standard cache m3.2xlarge Redis Previous Generation
cache.m3.2xlarge - 0.8550000000
OnDemand Cache Instance Standard cache m3.large Memcached Previous Generation
cache.m3.large - 0.2180000000
...
```